# Amazon EC2 Connect To Amazon Aurora MySQL, Spring Boot App

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I can connect my Spring Boot app on Elastic Beanstalk to my Amazon Aurora Database. I can connect MySQL Workbench to Amazon Aurora.

I have failed once already connecting my Spring Boot App on EC2 Linux to Amazon Aurora. I think it might be a security group issue. How do I connect an app on EC2 to an Amazon Aurora MySQL Database? I would like my security group to just allow my EC2 instance directly and any time I want to connect locally I do the setup each time by removing/adding my IP to the security group.

I can't use Elastic Beanstalk. Without going into details, I have a particular use case.

Comment: Ill try to include some examples in the next few days and clear up the question some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just allow the private ip of your EC2 instance in the security group of your Aurora DB.

Eg. If the private IP of your EC2 instance is 10.0.0.122, then add a security group Inbound entry on the security group of aurora with below properties.

Type : MySQL/Aurora
Protocol : TCP
Port Range :  3306
Source : Custom : 10.0.0.122/32

Comment: How do you most commonly get the private IP of your EC2 instance, after SSH login? Is it not displayed in the AWS web console?

Comment: you can use the command ifconfig and look into the "inet addr:" of the eth0 adapter